# custom radio tabIndex without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm able to apply tabindex on native radio buttons and use `tab` change the value with `arrow up` and `arrow down` on keyboard. But can I do the same with a custom radio where the actual `<input type="radio" />` is hidden?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7lgfpk?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:none;`, you can keep your native radio buttons and just restyle them so that they don't seem visible, but still function as you expect.

Just one of the approaches you can try in your `style.css`:

```
.radioBtn input {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to navigate with the `tab` key to your custom radio buttons group, you can enable that functionality to the radio label element:

```
const Radio = ({
  id,
  name,
  value,
  defaultChecked,
  onChange,
  children,
  tabIndex
}) => (
  <div
  className="radioBtn"
  >
    <input
      type='radio'
      defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
      value={value}
      id={id}   
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      tabIndex={tabIndex}
    />
    <label className="radio" htmlFor={id}  tabIndex={tabIndex}>
      <span className="big">
        <span className="small"></span>
      </span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
);
```